# Page goes blank when calling My bottomnavigation class

Tags: flutter

I have a created a bottom navigation bar on another page and when i am calling this class on my home page only home page is bottom navigation bar is showing there the app bar, drawer all becomes invisible
Help me with this!

This is my home.dart page on which i am calling my bottomNavigation class

```
import 'package:app_first/utilities/route.dart';
import 'package:app_first/widgets/bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:app_first/widgets/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttericon/font_awesome5_icons.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});


  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Center(
         child: Text("FOODIES@CU"),
        ),
      ),
      /*body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 40, width: double.infinity,),
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/background.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 500,
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 40,),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 2,color: Colors.orangeAccent,),
                )
              ),
              child: Text(
                "TOP RATED SHOPS",
                style: TextStyle(
                  
                  height: 2,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 35,),
            Container
            (decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 4),
            ),
              child: 
            Image.asset("assets/images/fr.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 300, height: 200,),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
               Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoute.loginroute);
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Text("FOOD REPUBLIC" , style: 
                TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),),
              ),
            ),


             SizedBox(height: 35,),
            Container
            (decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 4),
            ),
              child: 
            Image.asset("assets/images/fr.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 300, height: 200,),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
               Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoute.loginroute);
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Text("FOOD REPUBLIC" , style: 
                TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
          ),*/

   
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
      );
  }
}
```

And the bottomnavigation.dart page is here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(
    BottomNavigation()
  );
}

class BottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigation({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomNavigation> createState() => _BottomNavigationState();
}

class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        elevation: 100,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.home, color: Colors.indigo,),
          label: 'Home',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.shoppingCart, color: Colors.indigo,),
          label: 'Our services',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.bookOpen, color: Colors.indigo,),
          label: 'About us',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.phoneCall, color: Colors.indigo,),
          label: 'Contact us',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.settings, color: Colors.indigo,),
          label: 'Settings',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white70
          ),
        ]
        ),
        
      );
  }
}
```

[After running home.dart page i am only getting bottom navigation bar not appbar and anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzYI4.png)

Help me with this!

I have created two pages on flutter on first page named home.dart App bar is and drawer is there and i am calling bottomnavigation bar class which is created by me but when the code runs I am only getting bottom navigation bar not app bar and drawer
Help me with this!

Comment: Why are you running bottomnavigationclass directly ?

Comment: To get it displayed on my home page

Comment: No you are doing wrong

Comment: Please read proper : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Comment: you putted nothing inside the body of scaffold and directly apply bottomnav so your page is blank

Comment: App bar and drawer is their the body part is commented

Comment: After applying the body part the same thing happens the page is still blank

Comment: DebugService: Error serving requestsError: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isolateRef' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isolateRef
DebugService: Error serving requestsError: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isolateRef' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isolateRef
receiving this kind of error while putting my bottomnavigation class on my home.dart file